# Create algoritm for debt term calculation in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

For more than 3000 contracts, for each I have data of billed sum and payid sum. Payments usually != billed sum, there are can be multiple payments for one billed sum, can be some period without payments at all. For example some piece of data for a contract:

| date | type of operation | sum (billed) | sum (paid) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30.06.2021 | billed | 6919,07 |  |
| 31.07.2021 | billed | 4829,65 |  |
| 12.08.2021 | paid |  | 3000 |
| 31.08.2021 | billed | 3845,6 |  |
| 05.09.2021 | paid |  | 10000 |

It's needed to calculate average debt term for a contract, it means the time in days in between billed sum and its full payment. For instance, 6919,07 billed on 30.06.2021 fully paid on 05.09.2021 and for it's billed sum are two debt terms:

1. 3000 - debt term 43 days (remain part 3919,07) payd on 12.08.2021
2. 3919,07 - debt term 67 days

   remain part (3 080,93) of payment made on 05.09.2021 (10000) should be used for sum billed on 31.07.2021

**The main goal** - calculate over all contracts sum of debt < 1 month, 1-2 months, 2-5 month and more than 6 month, and calculate it every day to see in dynamic.

I only can imagined very complicated algoritm, with creation 2 addition tables for payment and debts like stack where stored only partly "used" sum, and also add flags for source tables to indicate if sum were fully paid.
May be it's better to use trees or another kind of data structures. But my "algoritm" is very complicated for programming and debuging.
Please help me to find more pithonic way to solve the issue.

Comment: You wrote that the debt term is the timespan between billing and **full** payment but then you mention a debt term of 43 days between billing and a partial payment?

Comment: yes, it is, but value of a sum decreased if some payment recieved

Comment: Is the date of the partial payment or the related debt term of 43 days somehow needed for the calculation of the result?

Comment: yes, it is needed to calculate parsial payment debt. The main goal - calculate over all contracts sum of debt < 1 month, 1-2 months, 2-5 month and more than 6 month, and calculate it every day to see in dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will show here only how to retrieve the date of full payment for all given billed debts with Python's standard library to better show how this works. It can be done faster with a library like pandas. The dates are strings here but the datatype doesn't matter for this code.

The idea is simply to find for the cumulative sum of bills up to a certain date the first date where the cumulative sum of payments is larger or equal.

**Step 1**

Separate tables for billed and payment events (stored as list of columns here):

```
billed = [["30.06.2021", "31.07.2021", "31.08.2021"],
        [6919.07, 4829.65, 3845.6]]

paid = [["12.08.2021", "05.09.2021"],
        [3000, 10000]]
```

**Step 2**

We need cumulative sums of billed and paid values (appended as new columns to the tables:

```
def cumulative(a):
    s = 0
    result = []
    for x in a:
        s += x
        result.append(s)

    return result


billed.append(cumulative(billed[1]))
paid.append(cumulative(paid[1]))
```

**Step 3**

Find and add dates of fully payment. Because the cumulative sum of paid debt is increasing (ordered), the bisect algorithm can be used:

```
from bisect import bisect_left

def get_paid_fully(s):
    """
    For given billed sum, return date when it is fully paid or None
    """

    p = bisect_left(paid[2], s)
    if p == len(paid[2]):
        # Sum was never paid fully
        return None

    return paid[0][p]

billed.append(list(map(get_paid_fully, billed[2])))

print(billed)
```

`billed` finally contains additional columns for the cumulative sum (not needed anymore) and the date of the full payment of each bill:

```
[['30.06.2021', '31.07.2021', '31.08.2021'],
 [6919.07, 4829.65, 3845.6],
 [6919.07, 11748.72, 15594.32],
 ['05.09.2021', '05.09.2021', None]]
```